# zcat filename expansion in for loop

Tags: bash, unix, zcat

I got these files:

```
bonds.txt.gz
bonds_201307.txt.gz
bonds_201308.txt.gz
bonds_201309.txt.gz
bonds_201310.txt.gz
bonds_201311.txt.gz
bonds_201312.txt.gz
```

I have a for loop to go through the files, uncompress them, and find a string with grep:

```
for f in `ls *.txt.gz`; do echo $f; zcat $f | grep MYBOND; done
```

If I run this I get the following:

```
bonds.txt.gz
zcat: bonds.txt.gz.gz: No such file or directory
bonds_201307.txt.gz
zcat: bonds_201307.txt.gz.gz: No such file or directory
bonds_201308.txt.gz
zcat: bonds_201308.txt.gz.gz: No such file or directory
bonds_201309.txt.gz
zcat: bonds_201309.txt.gz.gz: No such file or directory
bonds_201310.txt.gz
zcat: bonds_201310.txt.gz.gz: No such file or directory
bonds_201311.txt.gz
zcat: bonds_201311.txt.gz.gz: No such file or directory
bonds_201312.txt.gz
zcat: bonds_201312.txt.gz.gz: No such file or directory
```

Seems like zcat is expanding the filename with an extra .gz
However its not doing it when I try to zcat a file from the command line just picks up the filename which is provided and doing its job. Why is it happening when called in a loop?

I know I can achieve the same by using zgrep or find, but still interested in understanding this behaviour of zcat. 
Thanks!

Comment: What version of `zcat` are you using? `zcat --version`

Comment: the version is: `zcat 1.3.5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your script, there is no issue, but if I set `alias ls='ls --color=always'`, I will have the same issue

maybe your `ls` returns some hidden characters like color code
can you try

```
for f in `\ls *.txt.gz`
```

but you could have used

`for f in *.txt.gz` instead of

```
for f in `ls *.txt.gz`
```

and if your system has `zgrep`, you could use `zgrep MYBOND $f` instead of `zcat $f | grep MYBOND`

The code will be like this:

```
for f in *.txt.gz; do echo "$f"; zgrep MYBOND "$f"; done
```

Comment: Thanks *.txt.gz is working fine. I mentioned btw that I know zgrep would work, but I just wanted to understand what is going on.

Comment: I updated my answer, please check whether your `ls` has alias `--color=always`

Comment: Try `ls *.txt.gz | cat -A` to see the hidden characters that `ls` is outputting.

Comment: Indeed. `alias ls='ls --color'`. This messed it up. With `\ls` it's working. Thanks!